# Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?

Tags: excel, vba, range

It is pretty much widely accepted that this is not 'best practise'.

```
dim rng as range
with thisworkbook    '<~~ possibly set an external workbook 
    with .worksheets("sheet1")
        set rng = .range(cells(2, 1), cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))
    end with
end with
```

The two [Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) properties that define the scope of the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) will default to the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx). If this is not Sheet1 (defined as the [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) in the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)), the assignment will fail with,

```
Run-tim error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Solution: use `.Cells` not `Cells`. Case closed.

### **But...**

Is the `.` necessary in this [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) definition when both the [Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) properties inherit the [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) worksheet property that is defined in the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)?

How can this,

```
dim rng as range
with thisworkbook    '<~~ possibly set an external workbook 
    with .worksheets("sheet1")
        ' define rng as Sheet1!A2 to the last populated cell in Sheet1!A:A
        set rng = .range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))  '<~~ .range
    end with
end with
debug.print rng.address(0, 0, external:=true)
```

... be different from this,

```
dim rng as range
with thisworkbook    '<~~ possibly set an external workbook 
    with .worksheets("sheet1")
        ' define rng as Sheet1!A2 to the last populated cell in Sheet1!A:A
        set rng = range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))  '<~~ range not .range
    end with
end with
debug.print rng.address(0, 0, external:=true)
```

We use `.range` when the parameters that define the scope of the range are ambiguous; e.g. `.range([A1])` The `A1` cell could be from any worksheet and will default to the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) without the `.`. But why do we need to reference the parent of a range object when the scope that defines it has properly referenced its parent worksheet?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My opinion is slightly different here.

**YES** it is required. You can't always control where the user may run the code from.

Please consider these few test cases

**SCENARIO**

Workbook has 2 worksheets. Sheet1 and Sheet2

---

**TEST 1 (Running from a module)**

Both Code give same result

**TEST 2 (Running from a Sheet code area of Sheet1)**

Both Code give same result

**TEST 3 (Running from a Sheet code area of Sheet2)**

```
'~~> This code fails
set rng = range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup))
```

You will get `Application Defined or Object defined` error

[image]

And hence it is always advisable to properly qualify your objects so that the code can run from anywhere

Comment: I am with Siddharth. It really depends on what's the "ActiveSheet", if the activesheet is a Chart Sheet, the bottom set of code errors out for sure, unless `.Range(...)` used.

Answer (score 9):

No, the `.` is not required where the cell references inside the brackets are qualified, unless the code is in a `Worksheet` module.  That said it is faster to run `set rng = .range(.cells(...), .cells(...))` than it is to run `set rng = range(.cells(...), .cells(...))` so including the `.` does some good.

For a `Worksheet` module, the `.` is required.

Comment: Makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 7):

The answer seems to be: only if the code is located in a Worksheet object.  I strongly suspect that this is because the Worksheet objects are the only ones that are both extensible and have a `Range` function.  When `Range` is called from a Worksheet, that object's `Range` function has scope. When the code is located in ThisWorkbook or a user module or class, the `Range` function with the closest available scope is the global `Range` object (assuming of course that there isn't a user defined `Range` function).  That one is tied to the `Application`, which *has to* resolve it based on the passed parameters and forward the call to the correct Worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped - I was actually a bit surprised when I was testing it.  Put the line `Debug.Print Range("A1").Parent.Name` in a Worksheet, then activate something else and run it.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - Actually, I'm not. It doesn't matter if the cell references are qualified or not -  `Range(Foo)` called from a Worksheet module will be evaluated as `Me.Range(Foo)`.  `Range(Foo)` called from anywhere else will evaluate as `ActiveSheet.Range(Foo)`. The arguments are irrelevant. In fact, since `Cells` has the same scope behaviour as `Range` vis-a-vis a Worksheet object exhibits exactly the same scope resolution issue.

Comment: I have to admit that the **Private** nature of a worksheet code sheet overrides the nature of the 'lone wolf' range object but at the same time you cannot define a range on a worksheet with the scope of cells from another worksheet unless you only use their string addresses.

Comment: @Jeeped - No worries, first doesn't mean the answer that you found most useful.  If you feel Siddharth's answer is more helpful either personally or to anyone else who might stumble across the question, don't hesitate to accept it on my account.

Comment: @Jeeped there's no such thing as 'lone wolf' range object. It's only a matter of scope - in worksheet's class module, you can reference all properties/methods of this sheet. If it's inside module - then it references Application.Range property. It's described in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx).

Comment: @BrakNicku no, it's a matter of COM spaghetti. An unqualified `Range` doesn't magically scopes to `Application`, it's scoped to the hidden `_Global` module, and ultimately resolves to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is. MSDN is telling dumbed-down half-truths that are thoroughly misleading if you're looking at the actual internals. Unqualified `Range` used in a worksheet's code-behind resolves to that sheet only because that's how scoping works in VBA; `Me` has a `Range` property, so unqualified `Range` is like `Me.Range`, just like `Me.TextBox1` is same as `TextBox1` in a form's code-behind.

Comment: Hence, because of how the same code scopes to different things depending on context, it's *definitely* a good idea to *always* qualify `Range` calls, be it only for readability/maintainability.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I agree almost 100% with your comments, and I'm fully aware how scope works inside a class module (in this case `Me` in Worksheet module class). I have never said that using using unqualified `Range` is a good idea. But do you have any example to show that `_Global.Range` behaves differently than `Application.Range`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug there's a sentence in MSDN _When used without an object qualifier, this property is a shortcut for ActiveSheet.Range_ - do you think it is confusing? I know that there is no "magic" involved and you can use almost all properties and methods of class Application without qualifing it only because hidden _Global class exists and have probably a set of very simple functions, you said it's all about "internals". Do you have access to internals of _Global class?

Comment: You are definitely doing a great job! I have never seen this tool before and if I ever come back to using VBA more actively, I'll definitely give it a try. You also definitely know way more than me about internals of `_Global` class, but I still think my comment you objected is valid. Shorthand but valid.