# setting dynamic range vba

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have been searching the web for a reason why my range won't work when referred to later on, but am a loss still. Any help is greatly appreciated!

What I am attempting to do is set a range based on a potentially moving last row (I import data and each week it grows). However, when I get to the  Set ExpenseNameRange, for some reason it is not considering it to be a range.

I need this to use later for a range in a sumproduct formula.

Below is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Dim Profitability As Worksheet
Dim Time As Worksheet
Dim Expense As Worksheet
Dim ExpenseValueRange As Range
Dim ExpenseNameRange As Range
Dim ExpenseDateRange As Range
Dim e As Integer
Dim d As Integer


Set Carryover = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2016 Carryover Forecast")
Set Profitability = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profitability")
Set Time = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SYNC Time")
Set Expense = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SYNC Expense")


finalrowexpense = Expense.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
**Set ExpenseNameRange = Expense.Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(finalrowexpense, 12))**
Set ExpenseDateRange = Expense.Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(finalrowexpense, 19))
Set ExpenseValueRange = Expense.Range(Cells(2, 23), Cells(finalrowexpense, 23))
For e = 37 To 63

            employeename = Carryover.Cells(e, 33).Value

            For d = 34 To 41

            If employeename <> "" Then

            ExpenseSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Month(ExpenseDateRange) = Month(Cells(35, d)), ExpenseNameRange = employeename)

            ExpenseSum = employeename.Offset(0, d).Value
```

Comment: try replacing that line with `Set ExpenseNameRange = Expense.Range(Expense.Cells(2, 12), Expense.Cells(finalrowexpense, 12))`

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
With Expense
  Set ExpenseNameRange = Range(.Cells(2, 12), .Cells(finalrowexpense, 12))
  Set ExpenseDateRange = Range(.Cells(2, 19), .Cells(finalrowexpense, 19))
  Set ExpenseValueRange =Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(finalrowexpense, 23))
End With
```

because, by itself, `Cells()` refers to the ActiveSheet.

**EDIT#1:**

Also you must fix the `Cells()` in the line with *SUMPRODUCT()*.

**EDIT#2:**

If the `Cells()` are qualified, the `Range()` does not need to be:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set r = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2))
        MsgBox r.Parent.Name
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would qualify the `Ranges` as well, for the same reason.

Comment: @DougGlancy  I do not understand.

Comment: I mean put periods in front of each "Range".

Comment: @DougGlancy  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: That's true! Thanks. Never thought of it that way. I would still do it though, for readability if nothing else. Got my vote.

Comment: re: *'If the Cells() are qualified, the Range() does not need to be'* See [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells) for an extended discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the awesome answers! I managed to follow the rabbit hole far enough and came up with something else that worked. It also looked like Sumifs was a much better option over sumproduct based on the reading I did. Sumifs don't call for arrays or any other special factors.

This is my looping code if anyone is interested.

```
Sub Organize_Expenses()

Dim Carryover As Worksheet
Dim Profitability As Worksheet
Dim Time As Worksheet
Dim Expense As Worksheet
Dim ExpenseValueRange As Range
Dim ExpenseNameRange As Range
Dim ExpenseMonthRange As Range
Dim ExpenseYearRange As Range
Dim VendorNameRange As Range
Dim e As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer


Set Carryover = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2016 Carryover Forecast")
Set Profitability = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profitability")
Set Time = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SYNC Time")
Set Expense = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SYNC Expense")
finalrowexpense = Expense.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set ExpenseNameRange = Expense.Range("L2:L" & finalrowexpense)
Set ExpenseMonthRange = Expense.Range("AC2:AC" & finalrowexpense)
Set ExpenseValueRange = Expense.Range("w2:w" & finalrowexpense)
Set ExpenseYearRange = Expense.Range("AD2:AD" & finalrowexpense)


            For d = 1 To 8
            For e = 37 To 56

            Employeename = Carryover.Cells(e, 33).Value

            If Employeename <> "" Then

            ExpenseSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ExpenseValueRange, ExpenseNameRange, Employeename, ExpenseMonthRange, d, ExpenseYearRange, "2016")



Carryover.Cells(e, 33).Offset(0, d).Value = ExpenseSum

            End If

            Next e

            Next d

 End Sub
```