# Excel VBA Using Variables in Cells and Range Function

Tags: vba, excel

I am tring to find the word "Example" in whole used cells. But the code gives me  Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”. I know there is something wrong with the line `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))` 
What could it be?

Thanks in advance.
Here is the Code:

```
Dim lastrow as Long
Dim lastcolumn as Long
Dim sclnr as Range
dim aws as WorkSheet

Set aws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Using UsedRange
lastrow = aws.UsedRange.Rows(aws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
lastcolumn = aws.UsedRange.Columns(aws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
'UsedRange works fine no problem with finding last row and column

Set sclnr = aws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Find("Example") 
'the word Example exits in one of the cells
```

Comment: yes it works thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a minute to take the [tour] (click it) to see how SO community works : accepting answers and upvotes.

Comment: See [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)

Comment: great article, thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You need to qualify all the range/cells references in case aws is not the active sheet when the macro is run.

```
Dim lastrow as Long
Dim lastcolumn as Long
Dim sclnr as Range
dim aws as WorkSheet

Set aws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Using UsedRange
lastrow = aws.UsedRange.Rows(aws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
lastcolumn = aws.UsedRange.Columns(aws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
'UsedRange works fine no problem with finding last row and column

Set sclnr = aws.Range(aws.Cells(1, 1), aws.Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Find("Example")
```

Comment: It works fine, I cannot thank you enough. It bugged me all day.

Comment: My pleasure. It's a very common problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test_MertTheGreat()
Dim FirstAddress As String, LookForString As String
LookForString = "Example"

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim SclnR As Range
Dim awS As Worksheet

Set awS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Using UsedRange
With awS.UsedRange
LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
LastColumn = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
End With 'awS.UsedRange

Set SclnR = awS.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Find("Example")
'the word Example exits in one of the cells

With awS.Range(awS.Cells(1, 1), awS.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
    .Cells(1, 1).Activate
    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set SclnR = .Find(What:=LookForString, _
                After:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
    If Not SclnR Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = SclnR.Address
        Do
            '''---+++--- Your actions here ---+++---
            Set SclnR = .FindNext(SclnR)
        'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not SclnR Is Nothing And SclnR.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```