# EXCEL VBA Application defined or object-defined error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I used to have a line

```
 Set rRng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:J20")
```

But as the range of cells can change from file to file (I2 is constant though), I found out an easy way to automate it.

The first cell from the range is always I2, and the last cell is J(last_pair_cell)

I thought that using Range(Cells(2,9), Cells(last_pair_cell), 10) would to the trick, but I'm getting error 1004...

This is the entire code:

```
Sub LoopRange2()

    Dim rCell1 As Range
    Dim rCell2 As Range
    Dim rRng1 As Range
    Dim rRng2 As Range

    Dim nCol As Integer                                     'Finds week column to insert values
    nCol = Worksheets("Clube").Range("P69").Value + 5


    'Find number of pairs that played the tournment
    Dim last_pair_cell As Integer
    Dim rngX As Range

    Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Range("A1:A10000").Find("Board", lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
        last_pair_cell = rngX.Row - 1
    End If



    **Set rRng1 = Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(last_pair_cell, 10))**
    'Set rRng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:J20")
    Set rRng2 = Worksheets("Clube").Range("C3:C80")         'IF ERROR CHANGE C80 TO C69

    For Each rCell1 In rRng1.Cells
        For Each rCell2 In rRng2.Cells
            If rCell2.Value = rCell1.Value Then
                Worksheets("Clube").Cells(rCell2.Row, nCol).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rCell1.Row, 6).Value
            End If
        Next rCell2
    Next rCell1

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Debug.print last_pair_cell` before the errored line to check the value

Comment: You state '*(I20 is constant though)*'. Do you mean `I2` or `J20` ?

Comment: I2 :) thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `Find` method to set `rngX`, here :

```
Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Range("A1:A10000").Find("Board", lookat:=xlPart)
```

However, if your `Find` was not able to find "Board", then `rngX` is `Nothing`, and you are not passing the following `If` criteria:

```
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
    last_pair_cell = rngX.Row - 1
End If
```

and `last_pair_cell` doesn't get the value of `rngX.Row - 1`, instead it still has the default value of `0`.

So setting your range with :

```
Set rRng1 = Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(last_pair_cell, 10))
```

Will throw an error, since `Cells(last_pair_cell, 10)` is actually `Cells(0, 10)` which throws an error.

Also, just to make sure your `rRng1` is fully qualified, use the correct syntax:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet_CSV")
    Set rRng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(last_pair_cell, 10))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no parent worksheet associated with the `Cells` within `Range`.

```
Set rRng1 = Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Range(Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Cells(2, 9), Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Cells(last_pair_cell, 10))

'or more succinctly as,

with Worksheets("Sheet_CSV")
    Set rRng1 =.Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(last_pair_cell, 10))
end with
```

See [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)

Answer (score 0):

to avoid running after parent worksheet qualification after the *first* one you could use `Resize()` method:

```
Set rRng1 = Worksheets("Sheet_CSV").Cells(2, 9).Resize(last_pair_cell - 1, 2)
```