# Error 2042 on application.match vba decimal numbers

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I cannot match the maximum value of a range into the same range. This with the purpose to know in which column i can find the maximum value.

im trying with this code

```
    Set rango = Range(Cells(45, W), Cells(46, W1))
                rango.Select
                maximo = WorksheetFunction.Max(rango)
               matching = Application.Match(CLng(maximo), Sheets("Dinamicos").Range(Cells(45, W), Cells(46, W1)), 0)
```

but i get the 2042 error. 
In this Section im trying to match percentages
if i use the code

```
    Set rango = Range(Cells(45, W), Cells(46, W1))
                rango.Select
                maximo = WorksheetFunction.Max(rango)
               matching = WorksheetFunction.Match.Match(CLng(maximo), Sheets("Dinamicos").Range(Cells(45, W), Cells(46, W1)), 0)
```

i get the runtime error 1004 Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction

Comment: You say you are having trouble with decimal numbers but you are using `CLng(maximo)` which is a long integer. Which is it?

Comment: yes, i have tried to solve this problem with Clng, but at the begining i left this decimal number without Clng and doesnt work either. i Saw this solution in a similar case so i try it in my code.

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(45, W), .Cells(46, W1)`needs to be a single row or single column. This looks like two rows and more than a single column.

Comment: related: [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)

Comment: Update: `.Range(.Cells(45, W), .Cells(46, W1)` can be multiple rows/column for `MAX` but not for `MATCH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLng` converts to a Long Integer essentially chopping off any decimal. Use `CDbl` to convert to a double.

```
dim maximo as double, matching as variant
with worksheets("sheet1")
    maximo = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range(.Cells(45, W), Cells(.46, W1)))
end with
with worksheets("Dinamicos")
    matching = Application.Match(CDbl(maximo),  .Range(.Cells(45, W), .Cells(46, W)), 0)
    if not iserror(matching) then
        'found a match in W; do something
        debug.print "found in W"
    else
        matching = Application.Match(CDbl(maximo),  .Range(.Cells(45, W1), .Cells(46, W1)), 0)
        if not iserror(matching) then
            'found a match in W1; do something
            debug.print "found in W1"
        end if
    end if
end with
```

You also left some dangling cell references in `Sheets("Dinamicos").Range(Cells(45, W), Cells(46, W1))` that I have attempted top tighten up.

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(45, W), .Cells(46, W1)`needs to be a single row or single column. This looks like two rows and more than a single column.

Comment: Update: `.Range(.Cells(45, W), .Cells(46, W1)` can be multiple rows/column for `MAX` but not for `MATCH`.

Comment: Is it possible to match  a  variable to discontinuous range ? i've been trying to use match function unsuccessfully. Do you have any sugerences to solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that if it failed matching on the `W` column then look in the `W1` column. I'll make an edit.