# How can I sort out this Worksheet Object?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been searching around and I am having trouble doing it, even if I tried many times but compilation failed. So, what I want to do is this (in a pretty simple and wrong form):

```
Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("A1") = Worksheets("Sheets2").Cells(3,Cells(3,8))
```

The `Cells(3,Cells(3,8))` is in the same Sheet.

Comment: Same sheet as in? Also are you sure it is `Sheets1, Sheets2` and not `Sheet1` or `Sheet2`

Comment: I mean that Cells(3,8) is in Sheets2. Oh and i put those Worksheet names as an example, not using those of course.

Comment: Then it should be `Worksheets("Sheets2").Cells(3,Worksheets("Sheets2").Cells(3,8))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells

Comment: Thanks man. Appreciate it.