# 'Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

i have never had an issue with this until now. Please take a look at the code below, it is on a Module in the workbook (not code on the worksheet), the code breaks when it tries to set a range.

```
Private Sub UpdateTickerList()
    Dim MyWS As Worksheet
    Dim a, b, c As Integer
    Dim NewStockRng As Range
    Dim RealTickFeed As Range
    'On Error Resume Next (i took this out to get the error)
    'initializes variables
    a = 0
    b = 0


    'defines the worksheet we are going to work on
    Set MyWS = Workbooks("Portfolio.xlsm").Worksheets("Feed")
    'finds last row
    b = MyWS.Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'finds how large is the new stock universe
    a = 8 'UBound(NPSeCompran)

    'defines a new range in which to copy the new symbols
    Set NewStockRng = MyWS.Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b + a - 1, 1)) 'i need to 
    'use b+a-1 to reflect the fact that if i
    'have row97 as my first row and 11 elements then i need to count row 97 
    'as#1, otherwise i end up with one more row
    'copies the stocks to the range
    NewStockRng.value = Application.Transpose(NPSeCompran)

    'now sort the list
    Set RealTickFeed = MyWS.Range("a3").CurrentRegion
    RealTickFeed.Sort key1:=MyWS.Range("a3"), Header:=xlYes

    'now get rid of duplicates
    RealTickFeed.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 9), Header:=xlYes

    ErrorHandler:
End Sub
```

Comment: btw, I put a=8 for now in reality the rest of the line is good

Comment: `Set NewStockRng = MyWS.Range(MyWS.Cells(b, 1), MyWS.Cells(b + a - 1, 1))`  ***ALL*** range objects need to specify the parent, or the inner range objects may be referring to a different sheet, thus the error.

Comment: Thank you! i know it was something stupid that i missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put **dots** on the `Cells()`:

```
Set NewStockRng = Range(MyWS.Cells(b, 1),MyWS.Cells(b + a - 1, 1))
```

*(there may be other problems)*

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a simple example:

```
Sub qwerty()
    a = 12
    b = 15
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Set MyWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set NewStockRng = Range(MyWS.Cells(b, 1), MyWS.Cells(b + a - 1, 1))

    MsgBox NewStockRng.Address(o, o) & vbCrLf & NewStockRng.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#2:**

The key issue is that `Cells()` is already  tiny range itself.  Thus:

```
Range(whatever.Cells(1,1), whatever.Cells(3,3))
```

is fully qualify.

Comment: don't you want `MyWS.` in front of `Range(...` also?

Comment: @ScottCraner  You don't need to qualify `Range()` if you have already qualified `Cells()` within.

Comment: Would that not give the same error, that Range would be looking at the activesheet while the cells are looking at another?

Comment: @ScottCraner  See my **EDIT#1** for a specific example.

Comment: Yeah, all my life I have been living a lie.......Interesting, another assumption down the drains.

Comment: The joys of VBA. I remember spending an hour trying to work out what was wrong with my code before I learnt that exact lesson.

Comment: Now, I strictly only ever use the unprefixed `Range` method for the purpose of getting the range between two `ws.Range` ranges. I never use the unprefixed, and only use the prefixed, `ws.Cells`, `ws.Columns`, `ws.Rows` or `ws.Range` methods.

Comment: related: [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)