# Pasting Values Only using VBA: Error "Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the Range class

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a small macro to work. Basically, all I want to change is making it paste only values.

I did not write most of this code, only a few snippets. And it goes like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LRSrc As Long, LRDest As Long, SrcRng As Range

With Sheets("Input sheet")
    LRSrc = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'assumes column 1 is contiguous
    Set SrcRng = .Range("A2:G" & LRSrc)
End With
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:G2")) = 0 Then
Dim emptyErr As Integer
emptyErr = MsgBox("Data missing or incomplete! Please type in all the fields, starting from row 2", vbOKOnly, "No data")

Else

With Sheets("General inventory")
    LRDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    SrcRng.Copy .Cells(LRDest + 1, 2)
End With
Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Data sent to inventory! Do you wish to clear the sheet?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")
If answer = vbYes Then
    SrcRng.ClearContents

End If

End If

End Sub
```

I tried to solve it making these changes:

```
With Sheets("General inventory")
    LRDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    SrcRng.Copy .Cells(LRDest + 1, 2).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
End With
Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Data sent to inventory! Do you wish to clear the sheet?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")
If answer = vbYes Then
    SrcRng.ClearContents
```

But it gives me the error

> Runtime error '1004':
>
> Unable to get the paste special property of the Range class

I have no idea of how to fix it, or whether I should be using `PasteSpecial` at all.

I appreciate the time you may have taken to read this, and thank you for any advice you may give.

Cheers,

David.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're interested in pasting values only, a one liner would be:

```
.Cells(LRDest + 1, 2).Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, SrcRng.Columns.Count).Value = SrcRng.Value
```

and to shorten the whole thing down a little bit more:

```
With Sheets("General inventory")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, SrcRng.Columns.Count).Value = SrcRng.Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can paste values with 1 line in VBA, so you'll need to split that into two lines:

```
SrcRng.Copy
.Cells(LRDest + 1, 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```