# What is wrong with the following VBA Code related to range selection?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set dr = Range(Selection, Cells(Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp)(xlToRight))
```

Basically, I want to select a whole range spanning across numerous rows and columns with data being populated interspersed

It works perfectly upto Xlup. But when I add Xltoright, it doesn't take effect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nklwi.png)

Comment: Share a screen-shot of your data, and highlight the range you are trying to `Select`. B.T.W, there's no need to `Select` the range, if you want later on to `Copy` it, you can directly `Copy` the range

Comment: Hi @ShaiRado , Thanks for replying. I don't want to copy the range. Rather I want to do something else

Comment: try doing it with `Set dr = Range(Selection, Cells(Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp).End(xlToRight))`

Comment: what do you think the `xlToRight` is doing on its own there?

Comment: also don't post your code in a picture. Post it here

Comment: `End(xlUp)(xlToRight)` ? This is not valid. Use `End(xlUp).End(xlToRight)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to go right and down of current selection then consider the following code.

As you later attempt to select in sheet 1 I am going to assume you actually meant `Worksheet("Sheet1")`.

If that is the case you can more safely do the following:

```
Sub hi()

    Dim dr As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set dr = .Range(Selection, .Cells(.Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp).End(xlToRight))

    End With

    Debug.Print dr.Address

End Sub
```

Note:

Bear in mind that `Cells` /`Range` without a qualifying Worksheet will use the **`Activesheet`**. See the excellent discussion here:

[Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells).

Synopsis:

With "." is faster, avoids potential for error 1004 and is generally considered best practice.

Comment: Did the above make sense or is there something further I need to add?