# excel vba range copy from one sheet to another (error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba, range, cells

I know there are a lot of topics related to the the error 1004 (object or app error) when you try to copy paste range from one sheet to another, but I do not understand something (I am still a beginner with VBA).

I have a Excel file with 2 sheets :

- "Worksheet1" with the data I want to copy
- "Feuil1" where I want to paste data with a specific layout

To understand my problem, take a look at my code

```
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim val4 as integer

    val4 = 4 
    a = 2
    b = 1

    For i = 1 To val4

        Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range(Worksheets("Worksheet1").Cells(a, 1), Cells(a + 2999, 1)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(2, b), Cells(a + 2999, b))

        a = a + 3000
        b = b + 1

    Next i
```

Note : in the full code, val4 was already used before this part.

When I try to run it, I obtain error 1004 (object or app error).
From what I have read, I believe the problem comes from "Cells" property where the working sheet must be specified (unlike range) but I do not understand why my code failed for copying.

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: I don't know if this would make a difference in a real non-testing operation but you could get rid of *b* and substitute *i*.

Comment: Suggest you read [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells) for a better understanding of defining a range using cells.

Comment: the i substitute changed Nothing for me.

Comment: I didn't say that it would; I said that *b* was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim a As Integer
  Dim b As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim val4 As Integer

  val4 = 4
  a = 2
  b = 1

  For i = 1 To val4
    WorkSheet1.Range(WorkSheet1.Cells(a, 1), WorkSheet1.Cells(a + 2999, 1)).Copy Feuil1.Range(Feuil1.Cells(2, b), Feuil1.Cells(a + 2999, b))
    a = a + 3000
    b = b + 1
  Next i
End Sub
```

You were on the right rack with what you said about the Cells bit messing it up.
The range(cells.....) must have the internal cells bit properly referenced. So each use of the word cells should be changed to worksheets(enter worksheet name in here).cells and then it will work.
The solution I've posted above is slightly neater I think due to it not using the tab labels that users can change. So in the VBA editor in the properties window you can give the sheet object a name.  I've called the first sheet worksheet1 and the second Feuil1 (Note ..this is not the tab name) now you can reference these objects directly in your code as I've shown above.
It should all work...

Answer (score 1):

Can you swop as below and fully qualify sheet references as this was causing issue

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim val4 As Long

    val4 = 4
    a = 2
    b = 1

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To val4

        With Worksheets("Worksheet1")
            Worksheets("Feuil1").Range(Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(2, b), Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(a + 2999, b)) = .Range(.Cells(a, 1), .Cells(a + 2999, 1))
        End With
        a = a + 3000
        b = b + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: "i" was not defined but I still have the 1004 error

Comment: did you intend for the copy to rows to increase beyond the initial copied 3000?

Comment: I made some scientific experiments and manage to combine all my results (txt files) in one excel file, but they are all following up in one column.
Every 3000 rows correspond to an experiment, and I want to get one column per experiment (I have 100 000+ results!)

Answer (score 0):

You are only specifying one of the parent worksheet references to the Cells that define Range. I'd suggest a With .... End With block and you only require the top-left cell for the destination to a Copy.

```
with Worksheets("Worksheet1")
    For i = 1 To val4
        .Range(.Cells(a, 1), .Cells(a + 2999, 1)).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(2, b)
        a = a + 3000
        b = b + 1
    Next i
end with
```

Comment: Do you actually have a worksheet named *Worksheet1* or should that be `with Worksheets("Sheet1")` ?

Comment: My sheet name is Worksheet1
I tried Sheet1 and I got an error 9
EDIT : in my language "Feuil1" means "Worksheet1"
calling issue?

Comment: after some tries, no issue with the sheet name

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim val4 As Integer

val4 = 4
a = 2
b = 1

For i = 1 To val4

    Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a + 2999, 1)).Copy Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(2, b)

    a = a + 3000
    b = b + 1

Next i
```

Comment: This code will work if you have the Worksheet1 sheet selected before you run the code. If you select anyother sheets then the .range ( cells(a,1) .......) will complain as the internal cells call isn't referenced properly.

Comment: If macro is triggered when different sheet is activated, you can add Worksheets(“Worksheet1”).Activate before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to speed it up by pasting values only instead of ranges

```
Sub test()
    Const chunksLength = 3000 ' define here your "chunks" length

    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Feuil1").UsedRange.Columns(1)
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count \ chunksLength + IIf(.Rows.Count Mod chunksLength > 0, 1, 0)
            .Offset(, i).Resize(chunksLength).Value = .Resize(chunksLength).Offset((i - 1) * chunksLength).Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```