# Advanced Filter: Excel VBA not working

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter all "X" in column F in the range A:F using Excel VBA. Here is the part of code. After selecting the autofilter it gives me a `Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed`. Help me out:

```
Function Advanced_Filter()

    Sheets("Email").Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
    Range("M2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "X"
    Range("A2:F2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A2:F244").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "Email!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range("M3"), Unique:=False
```

[image: This how the sheet looks like]

Comment: What scope are you working in?  In order to call `Range` without a qualifier, you must be within a worksheet's scope (where children of worksheet objects are implicitly qualified by the scoped sheet).  Otherwise you must define on which worksheet you want to get that range.

Comment: Sheet is "Email" and the entire macro runs on that sheet. so defining the sheet is not a problem. as said, I'm getting runtime error in the last line of the code.

Comment: The Range object needs an address or bounding cells passed in as a parameter. `Email!Criteria` is not a valid address. Change "Criteria" to the address of your criteria on the Email worksheet.

Comment: While I'm hesitant to provide a bandaid with no parent worksheet reference, `CriteriaRange:=Range("Criteria")` should temporarily resolve your issue. [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)

Comment: @greenarrow, any news?

Comment: no I tried changing the `Email!Criteria` to `Criteria`. didn't work that way. can't figure out what is the issue. can anyone suggest any alternative way out?

Comment: Tried this too `Range("A2:F244").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Email").Range("Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range("M3"), Unique:=False` didn't work out.