# Pull data from a corresponding cell in row A in last edited row and insert into cell A1

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a script that will pull data from last edited cell into Cell `B1` of active sheet and also look up data from cell in column `A` and then display it in cell `A1`.

So far I've got this to pull last edited cell into `B1` and it works fine but I cannot figure out how to then go back from that point to row `A` and display the other info.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("F13:W9910")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

In the attached picture if I add any numbers in section called trays completed (in red) to display in `B1` and then look up number in Sap column and display the number in cell `A1`

[image: Attached Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F13:W9910")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("B1").Value = Target.Value
        Me.Range("A1").Value = Target.Entirerow.Cells(1).Value
    End If   
End Sub
```

Note when in a sheet code module you can refer to the worksheet using `Me`
Also be aware that `Target` might be >1 cell and your code might need to handle that.

Comment: Is Me necessary when Range with no defined parent on a worksheet's private code sheet always belongs to that worksheet? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)

Comment: @Jeeped - no it's not, but I like to use it for the sake of being more explicit (and after spending years on SO telling folk to never use unqualified ranges)

Answer (score -1):

This will take the corresponding value in A and place it in A1. I only added one line of code to yours.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("F13:W9910")) Is Nothing 
Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = Target.Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Target.Row)  
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Another sub procedure (bulk data load perhaps...?) could conceivably write a value into F13:W9910 and trigger this worksheet's Worksheet_Change when this worksheet is not the ActiveSheet.