# Excel VBA Macro Won't Delete cells when another sheet is active

Tags: excel, vba

The below code produces the error "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object"_Worksheet' failed" if the referenced sheet is not active. However, If I have the sheet active and run the code everything works. I believe the worksheet in question is properly set as an object for the code to reference and I have tried several different setups to target it.

```
Private Sub clearImport()
Dim Ws As Worksheet


Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Returned")
k = Ws.Range("P65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(k, 23)).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells` is referring to the `ActiveSheet` while `Range` is looking at the _Returned_ sheet. It should be  `Ws.Range(WS.Cells(2, 1), WS.Cells(k, 23)).Delete`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I thought the reference carried through from the Ws object.

Comment: You should also add `Dim k As Long` and go into `Tools ~ Options` and tick `Require Variable Declaration` on the `Editor` tab.

Comment: Afraid not.  You could use [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) to shorten it a bit though.

Comment: Welcome to the club - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Range%28Cells%28%22+1004 This is really the most common error in the VBA tag, without a doubt. I guess that everyone has hit it once and wondered a bit what was wrong.

Comment: Might be worth using `ClearContents` rather than `Delete` if you're getting `#REF!` errors after deleting.

Comment: [Interesting read.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)